# Svelte Stores & Jest

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, svelte, svelte-store

I'm looking for an way to mock/stub stores that are used in Svelte components, specifically with the auto-subscribe syntax (ie `$myStore` or `$myStore.property`).

I've tried a couple of different mocks, mostly along the lines of the following:

```
jest.mock('./stores/users', () => ({
  currentUser: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() =>
    writable({
      isAdmin: true,
    }),
  ),
}));
```

The test will error out on any auto-subscribed references to the store, which are undefined. For example, if I am referencing a store from `"../../stores/users"` in my component like so...

```
{#if $user.isAdmin}
  <div>Hello I'm an admin</div>
{/if}
```

... then I receive `TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAdmin' of undefined`

It seems that even when mocking a Svelte store, the `$` auto-subscribe syntax is not breaking the test. I should point out that when logging the mocked store, the expected Svelte store methods (`subscribe()`, `set()` and `update()`) are there, and executing the `subscribe()` method exposes the `isAdmin` attribute also as expected.

I can't seem to find any established unit testing patterns that deal with Svelte and the use of stores, so any and all input on the topic would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue, only I'm trying to assign a value rather than read it (`$sequence.events = sequenceEvents;`). Everything works fine if I use the longer format (`sequence.update(…)`).

Answer (score 1):

The `$` shortcut is unique to svelte. You cannot access it outside of a svelte application.

However, you can achieve the same thing using the `get` function exported from svelte/store, which will subscribe, read and immediately unsubscribe just like the `$` shortcut you're wanting to use:

```js
import { get } from 'svelte/store'
import store from './stores/users' //- change to your path

const user = get(store)
expect(user.isAdmin).toEqual(true)
```